# Whether I should use Asynctask or a service to update Database in Android

Tags: android, database

My requirement is to get data from a webpage and update in the  Android Database (A simple table) and from there I will be  querying the database to send out notifications

Whether I should use Async task or Service for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use AsyncTask definitely. Service here is a big overhead.

In general AsyncTask are used when you do small things(3-5 seconds) and this is ok to show a progress dialog. Services are for long processing background tasks.

Comment: My task is background task which will update Database and then will send out a notification and will update UI.Whether updating UI can be done in Async task?

Comment: Of course. Do all you db work in doInBackground() method and notify the UI in onPostExecute(). See an example: http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer! Click the tick in the left of it.

Comment: Whether this can repeated using a timer loop every 1 -2 minutes??

Answer (score 0):

> get data from a webpage and update in the Android Database (A simple table)

Use asyn task when you want to update from web to your local, its better and accurate way.

> Whether I should use Async task or Service for it?

In your case, you should use [Asyn Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead service.